# @input no actualiza mi tabla, VUEJS

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

Estoy realizando un input en el cual a la hora de ingresar cualquier dato que este en la base de datos este me lo retorne, lo cual funciona, solo que se actualiza si es muy especificio, ejemplo hay un producto que se llama weisen u 100 y otro weisen u 30, a medida que vaya escribiendo weisen me deberia mostrar ambos, lo hace, si escribo completamente weisen u 30, me muestra solo este, pero al borrar el 30, me deberia mostrar tanto el weisen u 100 como el weisen 30, pero no se por que no lo hace, se queda mostrandome weisen u 30, aqui el codigo:

js:

```
findproduct: function() {
        this.listFinishedproducts = this.listFinishedproducts.filter(products => {
            return products.lot.match(this.product.toLowerCase()) 
            || products.name.match(this.product.toLowerCase());
        })
    }
```

tambien esta hecho para que si escriba el lot me devuelva los productos que tengan numeros de ese lot o que sea igual a ese lot, espero que me hayan entendido :), aqui la vista por si acaso:

```
 <input v-model="product" @input="findproduct"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Has intentado cambiarlo a la directriva `@change ="findproduct"`

Comment: si, pero con change tengo que darle enter para que me lo actualice, con @input es lo adecuado pero por alguna razon no lo hace

Comment: y nativo de html onkeypress?

Comment: Tu lista debes agregarla a una propiedad computada que este revisando el cambio de `product` o agregar este ultimo a una función `watch`